# special characters in sql text

Tags: sql, char

I have a problem with special char in SQL queries.

So I would to insert a field "text" in a table with the command:

```
INSERT INTO description(Text) VALUES ('$text');
```

So, if in the variable `$text` there are special chars the query not works!
How can I resolve?

Comment: What is the datatype of `text` field

Comment: you use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), they are much safer!

Comment: datatype means character type?
Latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MSSQL SERVER** you can also do something like this

```
INSERT INTO description(Text) VALUES (N'$text')
```

Comment: @AndreaGiordano: for MySql  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html